# How do I select rows based on the value of a multiple columns and comparing values of those columns in the resultset?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table as follows :

```
A|  B|  C|  D|
1   3   1   25/2/2016
2   4   2   25/4/2016
2   5   1   22/2/2016
3   5   1   23/2/2016
3   5   1   23/6/2016
```

Now I want the result set with following condition :

- All rows with value of B as 3 or 4.
- Include rows with value of B as 5 only when the value of A is unique
  for it.

For e.g. in the above table as the value of A is 2 for the row where value of B is 5 ,and an row with value of A as 2 is already present with value of B as 4, this row would not be included.

- But the row where value of B is 5 and value of A is 3 will be
  included because there is no row where value of A is 3 and value of B
  is 3 or 4.
- Also, there are 2 such rows where value of A is 3 and B is 5, so I
  want to select the one with the latest value of D.

Desired output table :

```
A|  B|  C|  D|
1   3   1   25/2/2016
2   4   2   25/4/2016
3   5   1   23/6/2016
```

Comment: Please provide desired output as a table, it will be much easier to read your question

Answer (score 1):

Another way with OUTER APPLY:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b34.*
FROM YourTable y
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1    *
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE y.A = A AND B IN (3,4,5)
    ORDER BY B,D DESC
    ) b34
```

Output:

```
A   B   C   D
1   3   1   2016-02-25
2   4   2   2016-04-25
3   5   1   2016-06-23
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create sub-query/CTE for the unique A's for B=5. and join it with your data.

```
with unqA as (
   select A,max(D) D 
   from data 
   group by A
   having max(B)=5 and min(B)=5)
select d.A,d.B,d.C,d.D
from data d
   left join unqA  u on (d.B=5 and d.A = u.A and d.D  = u.D)
where d.B in (3,4) or u.A is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a prioritization query.  I would handle this using `rank()` with the logic in the `order by`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             rank() over (partition by a
                          order by (case when b in (3, 4) then 1 else 2 end),
                                   (case when b not in (3, 4) then d end) desc
                         ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This is using two keys for the `order by`.  When `b` is 3 or 4, then the first key is 1 and the second `NULL` -- all such rows are returned.  When something is not 3 or 4, then only the newest one is returned.

Your question suggests that a given value of `a` could have multiple rows with 3/4, this would return all of them.